# Why does my application have redirection issues when the appPool runs under a v2.0 .NET Framework?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, windows-server-2008, upgrade

I have a web application which has been having a strange issue ever since I moved it to a new server. Users will be able to use the application for some time, but after a few page requests, they will be redirected to the default page and asked to log in again. For some reason, this issue occurs less and less the more the application is used. The issue then starts occurring again over night. The application was formerly running on a windows 2003 server and it worked fine there, so I believe the issue has something to do with the settings on the new server.

I am currently running the application on a windows 2008 server with IIS 7.

I looked through a bunch of different settings in IIS and changed many different things, but none of them seemed to solve the problem. But today, I tried changing the application pool to run under a v4.0 .NET Framework, and that seemed to solve the problem. The application pool formerly ran under a v2.0 .NET Framework.

I do not understand how changing the framework solved my problem. I do not see any connection between the .NET Framework version and my application redirecting to the default page.

Can anybody explain how / why this change in settings solved my issue? Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you